# How to add data android:scheme programmatically in Manifest

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I develop an app with dropbox support.

Is there any way to add `<data android:scheme="db-INSERT-APP-KEY-HERE" />` in my app manifest programmatically?

I want end user can change the `APP-KEY` from my app.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to supply some data to user and want user to change this data later. You can use local db to do this.  For example, create table which will holds the key than let the user update this row.

[EDIT 1]

Dropbox api needs to key one of them is **APP_KEY** and other is **SECRET**, when you develop applicaiton for your customer you must know **app_key**, your customer must give it to you.

But you customer dont have to give his secret to you,

```
final static private String APP_KEY = "INSERT_APP_KEY_HERE";
final static private String APP_SECRET = "INSERT_SECRET_HERE";
```

INSERT_SECRET_HERE you can check a local db for this value, if there aren local db which have table. You should ask you customer to give its secret_key and save this secret to db.

final static private String APP_SECRET = set this with the value from your local db

Comment: How can I pass the data to android manifest in order to authenticate to dropbox account?

Comment: I dont understand why do you need ? it is your app key, why do you want user to change it ?

Comment: I develop an app for a customer of mine and I want to change it on his own

Comment: Pls look at the edited answer. You must know your customer APP_KEY but you dont need to know his secret

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, I develop an app for multiple customers of mine and I want, if it is possible, to fill the KEY and SECRET code without the need of manually edit the APP_CODE in MANIFEST, which is mandatory, with eclipse... thx for your time

Comment: I thing there are a on logical problem your side. Let me explain, it is your android application and it uses dropbox api. For example you are using the api to reach App folder. It is not mean user will reach your app folder. It mean they will reach their app_folder by using your dropbox application. Like facebook or twitter  when you use facebook api in your android application you need an app and secret also, and users will reach their information using your facebook app.

Comment: Let me explain it to you. The app I develop supports dropbox. I want the clients of mine to be able to connect to their dropbox account in order to download or upload some files. So I want them to be able to add to the app their APP and SECRET codes on their own without the need of my help. And I need to add it in the manifest also. Thx again